# Calculating 3D affine transform and re-sampling a volume using that

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, affinetransform, image-registration

I am trying to register two volumes(`vol1` and `vol2`). The size of the `vol1` is `40x40x24`. The size of the `vol2` is `64 x64x11`.

So far, I have extracted their features and then matched them. Now, I have a set of corresponding points in two volumes that is stored in `pairs` which is a matrix of size `100x6` (every row of `pairs` is `[x y z X Y Z]` where `(x,y,z)` are the coordinates of a voxel in `vol1` and `[X Y Z]` is the corresponding voxel in `vol2`). Then, using RANSAC algorithm, I have calculated the 3D affine transform, T. For example, T is something like below:

```
T=
    2.7791    0.8204    0.7561  -61.6055
   -0.4418    2.2663   -1.9882   29.0375
   -0.2120    0.6568   -0.7041    6.2702
         0         0         0    1.0000
```

I have a couple of questions. First, does this affine transformation matrix look correct? It looks correct to me. If it is correct then why the function **[affine3d](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affine3d-class.html)** in MATLAB which calculates the 3D affine transform has the column of zeroes instead of the row of zeroes (like in T above)? It looks like the transpose of my transform T.

If my transform is correct then another problem occurs. I tried to resample vol1 using transform T, but the calculated voxel coordinates are negative!!! I am so confused. I do not know what causes this problem.

Here, is my code. Please let me know if you see any problem with it.

```
function [ vol1R ] = resampling(vol1, vol2, T)

[size1, size2, size3] = size(vol2);
vol1R = zeros(size1,size2,size3); % Initializing registered vol1

for i= 1:size1
    for j= 1:size2
        for k = 1:size3
            V = [i;j;k;1]; % V is the coordinates of a voxel on the registered vol1
                           % correspoding to voxel v on the  vol1
                           % V = T * v : Relationship between v and V

            v = T\V;       % Problem occurs here!!!!!!! v has some negative values
                           % v (coordinates in vol1)
            % continue 
        end

     end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of your affine matrix looks fine if you are using it to operate on column vectors, as in `[X; Y; Z; 1] = T*[x; y; z; 1]`. The reason MATLAB's example is transposed is because it operates on `1x4` row vectors, as in `[X, Y, Z, 1] = [x, y, z, 1]*(T')`.

As for the the actual numbers in the matrix, I can't comment since I don't know the original images. I do notice that there is an x-translation of `-61.6055`, which seems pretty big for the sizes of the images you have. Do you know for sure this is the right answer?

I'd suggest maybe starting with a simple pair of images where you know the answer beforehand (maybe white squares on a black background drawn in Paint) to confirm your registration algorithm gives the right answer.